# Extracting text from file and output the line into a file

Tags: command-line, bash

After using grep on an html file, I get the following output:

```
      <div id="v3060000-3062005" class="BLAH...>
      <div id="v50001027-50002018" class="BLAH...>
      <div id="v907200-907202" class="BLAH...>
      <div id="v20024011-20024012" class="BLAH...>
```

I need to extract the strings of numbers from the lines above and combine them into a URL such as:

```
http://x.y.z/3060000-3062005,50001027-50002018,907200-907202,20024011-20024012.mp3
```

May I know how I can do this using a shell script?

Answer (score 6):

Normally, I would advise that you use a proper HTML parser to parse HTML.

However, this data looks pretty straightforward: using a double quote (optionally followed by "v") as the field separator, grab the 2nd field of each line. Then join the pieces with commas

```
result=$( grep ... file.html | awk -F'"v?' '{print $2}' | paste -sd, )
echo "http://x.y.z/$result.mp3"
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have the input data from your question stored in a file called `data.txt`, you can use this command to generate the URL:

```
grep -Po '\d+-\d+' data.txt | tr '\n' ',' | sed -r 's/(.*),$/http:\/\/x.y.z\/\1.mp3/'
```

Here is an example run:

```
$ grep -Po '\d+-\d+' data.txt | tr '\n' ',' | sed -r 's/(.*),$/http:\/\/x.y.z\/\1.mp3/'
http://x.y.z/3060000-3062005,50001027-50002018,907200-907202,20024011-20024012.mp3
```

What it does:

- `grep -Po '\d+-\d+' data.txt` extracts all the `NUMBER-NUMBER` sequences from your data, like `3060000-3062005` and outputs one sequence per line.
- `tr '\n' ','` converts all the newline characters of its input to commas, effectively joining the lines together.
- `sed -r 's/(.*),$/http:\/\/x.y.z\/\1.mp3/'` removes the trailing comma from its input and embeds it into the string `http://x.y.z/\1.mp3`, replacing `\1`. Note that all slashes in the string must be escaped with a backslash.

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`:

```
... | awk -F'"' '{part=part substr($2,2) ","} \
                  END {sub(",$", "", part); print "http://x.y.z/" part ".mp3"}'
```

- `-F'"'` sets the field separator as `"`
- `part=part substr($2,2) ","}` gets the second field, and `substr($2,2)` gets strips off the starting `v` from string, and the result is saved with adding a trailing `,` as variable `part`
- `END {sub(",$", "", part); print "http://x.y.z/" part ".mp3"}` chunk is run after parsing all records, here we are stripping off the last `,` from variable `part`, and printing the desired formatted output

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
      <div id="v3060000-3062005" class="BLAH...>
      <div id="v50001027-50002018" class="BLAH...>
      <div id="v907200-907202" class="BLAH...>
      <div id="v20024011-20024012" class="BLAH...>

% awk -F'"' '{part=part substr($2,2) ","} END {sub(",$", "", part); print "http://x.y.z/" part ".mp3"}' file.txt
http://x.y.z/3060000-3062005,50001027-50002018,907200-907202,20024011-20024012.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to figure out how to get the text you need to output. Since other answers show how to do this, I won't need to include that information in my answer.

However, I will be addressing how to output that information into a file.

To do this, insert `> filename` after your command. This will overwrite the file's contents (creating it if it doesn't exist) with the standard output (stdout) of the command used.

An alternative method is to use `>>` instead of `>` to append the text to a file instead, rather than overwriting it.